# Combine browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived url's programmatically

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm grabbing some urls from browser.storage and I'm trying to combine them. Is this possible?

Example:

```
var testurls = "'*://site1.com/*'," + "'*://site2.com/*'";
browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(setHeader,
    {urls: [testurls]},
    ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']
);
```

Comment: [`urls`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/RequestFilter#Type) is an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of [match patterns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns), not a comma separated list contained in a single string.

Answer (score 0):

As Mayken notes, in the comment, `urls` property is an Array.

Which, immediately, suggests that it supports multiple items.

```
browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(setHeader,
    {urls: ['*://site1.com/*', '*://site2.com/*']},
    ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']
);
```

Comment: any idea how i can capture requests and responses of a `webview`?